# NSURLRequest with HTTPBody input stream: Stream sends event before being opened

Tags: iphone, nsurlconnection, nsstream

I want to send a large amount of data to a server using `NSURLConnection` (and `NSURLRequest`). For this I create a bound pair of `NSStream`s (using `CFStreamCreateBoundPair(...)`). Then I pass the input stream to the `NSURLRequest` (`-setHTTPBodyStream:`) and schedule the output stream on the current run loop. When the run loop continues, I get the events to send data and the input stream sends this data to the server.

My problem is, that this only works when the data fits into the buffer between the paired streams. If the data is bigger, then somehow the input stream gets an event (I assume "bytes available") but the NSURLConnection has not yet opened the input stream. This results in an error message printed and the data is not being sent.

I tried to catch this in my `-stream:handleEvent:` method by simply returning if the input stream is not yet opened, but then my output stream gets a stream closed event (probably because I never sent data when I could).

So my question is: How to use a bound pair of streams with NSURLConnection correctly?

(If this matters: I'm developing on the iOS platform)

Any help is appreciated!

Cheers, Markus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I kind of fixed this by starting the upload delayed, so that it starts after the `NSURLConnection` had time to setup its input stream.

It's not what I call a clean solution though, since relying on `-performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:` seems a bit hacky.

So if anyone else has a solution to this, I'm still open for any suggestions.

Comment: I don't have access to this project anymore. But it was just this (pseudocode):

    StartNSURLConnection()
    Delay(1sec, {
        StartSendingDataToStream()
    })

Comment: But as I said, it's not really a stable solution ufortunately. You should take a look at NSURLSession, they might have improved stream handling: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Articles/UsingNSURLSession.html